# Security exceptions

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to configure security exceptions to all JavaScript/CSS of my pages.

I need to login to access the JSP files, except the `login` page, but all pages needs your resources so the folders must be access-free.

```
.csrf().disable()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/login*").anonymous()
.antMatchers("/bower_components/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/custom/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/plugins/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/dist/**").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()

.formLogin()
.loginPage("/loginPage")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
.failureUrl("/loginPage?error=true")
.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
.usernameParameter("username")
.passwordParameter("password")
.and()

.logout()
.logoutSuccessUrl("/loginPage")
.invalidateHttpSession(true);
```

Comment: Hi Jamal. The text has lost its meaning / purpose  when you removed the `the code seems ugly` part of original question. 
I need to know if the code in question is as elegant as possible and without the original text the users may not know what I mean. Someone may flag as `obscure`...